# Actualizar registros en codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Que tal soy nuevo utilizando este framework, el problema que tengo es que al actulizar un registro de un usuario que tiene el mismo nombre en la base de datos, se me actualiza con los datos del primer usuario que esta registrado con el mismo nombre en la base de datos.
nota: esto solo pasa con el campo nombre, espero que me puedan ayudar.

[image: tabla users]

[image: tabla tutoria]

```
public function EditarReAdm(){
   $idtutoria = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $obtenerDatosRegistro= $this->Principalmodel->obtenerDatosRegistro($idtutoria);
    if($obtenerDatosRegistro != FALSE){
        foreach ($obtenerDatosRegistro->result() as $row){
            //$idtutoria=$row->idtutoria;
            $Nombre=$row->Nombre;
            $Apellido=$row->Apellido;
            $Carrera= $row->Carrera;
            $Numtuto=$row->Numtuto;
            $Fecha=$row->Fecha;
            $HoraI=$row->HoraI;
            $HoraF=$row->HoraF;
            $Ubicacion=$row->Ubicacion;
            $Nota=$row->Nota;
             if($HoraI=="00:00:00" && $HoraF=="00:00:00"){
                        $HoraI=" ";
                        $HoraF=" ";
                        }
        }
        $data = array(
                'idtutoria'=>$idtutoria,
                'Nombre'=>$Nombre,
                'Apellido'=>$Apellido,
                'Carrera'=>$Carrera,
                'Numtuto'=>$Numtuto,
                'Fecha'=>$Fecha,
                'HoraI'=>$HoraI,
                'HoraF'=>$HoraF,
                'Ubicacion'=>$Ubicacion,
                'Nota'=>$Nota,
            );
    }else{
        return FALSE;
    }
    $this->load->view('head/librerias_view');
    $this->load->view('Menu/MenuAdministrador');
    $this->load->view('FEditarReAdm',$data);

}

ublic function actualizar() {
    if (!$this->tank_auth->is_logged_in()) {
        redirect('/auth/login/');
    } else {
    $num=0;
    $mi_archivo='mi_archivo';
    $idtutoria=$this->input->post('idtutoria');
    $idusuario=$this->input->post('idusuario');
    $Archivo=$this->input->post('Archivo');
    if($this->input->post('Nombre')==" "||$this->input->post('Apellido')== " "){
    $Nombre = $this->db->select('username')->from('users')->where('id', $idusuario)->get()->row()->username;
    $Apellido = $this->db->select('Apellido')->from('users')->where('username', $Nombre)->get()->row()->Apellido;
}else{
      $Nombre = $this->input->post('Nombre');
      $Apellido = $this->input->post('Apellido');
      $Apellido = $this->db->select('Apellido')->from('users')->where('username', $Nombre)->get()->row()->Apellido;
}
    $Carrera = $this->input->post('opcarrera');
    $Numtuto = $this->input->post('optuto');
    $Lugar = htmlspecialchars($this->input->post('Ubicacion'));
    $Fecha = $this->input->post('Fecha');
    $HoraI = $this->input->post('HoraI');
    $HoraF = $this->input->post('HoraF');
    $Nota = htmlspecialchars($this->input->post('Nota'));
    $config['upload_path'] = FCPATH ."Tutorias/";
    $Nombrepunto= str_replace('.', '', $Nombre);
    $NombreArchivo=$Nombrepunto.$Carrera.$Numtuto;
    $Acentos=strtr($NombreArchivo,'àáâãäçèéêëìíîïñòóôõöùúûüýÿÀÁÂÃÄÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÑÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝ',
    'aaaaaceeeeiiiinooooouuuuyyAAAAACEEEEIIIINOOOOOUUUUY');
    $Espacios = str_replace(' ', '', $Acentos);
    $config['file_name'] = $Espacios; //nombre del archivo
    $config['max_size'] = "50000";// tamaño maximo
    $config['max_width'] = "2000";//
    $config['max_height'] = "2000";
    $config['overwrite']=TRUE;// que pueda sobreescribir
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'pdf'; //solo extencion pdf
        $data=array(


                        //Datos a insertar o actualizar
                //'idtutoria'=>$idtutoria,
                'Nombre'=>$Nombre,
                'Apellido'=>$Apellido,
                'Carrera'=>$Carrera,
                'Numtuto'=>$Numtuto,
                'Ubicacion'=>$Lugar,
                'Fecha'=>$Fecha,
                'HoraI'=>$HoraI,
                'HoraF'=>$HoraF,
                'Nota'=>$Nota,
                'Archivo'=>$Archivo,
                );

    $this->load->library('upload', $config); //cargar libreria Upload

       // $idtutoria = $this->db->select('idtutoria')->from('tutoria')->where('Nombre', $Nombre)->where('Carrera', $Carrera)->where('Numtuto', $Numtuto)->get()->row()->idtutoria;// consulta para obtener id de la seleccion
        if($Archivo!=0){
        if (!$this->upload->do_upload($mi_archivo)) {//preguntamos si hubo algun error de configuracion del archivo
        //*** ocurrio un error
        //$data['uploadError'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
        $this->load->view("errorArchivo");// cargamos vista de error
        }else{
    $data1['uploadSuccess'] = $this->upload->data();//subimos el archivo
   $this->db->where('idtutoria',$idtutoria);   
    $this->db->update('tutoria',$data);//insertamos un nuevo registro
    redirect('welcome/exito');// Cargamos vista exito
    }
    }else{
         $this->db->where('idtutoria',$idtutoria);   
         $this->db->update('tutoria',$data);//insertamos un nuevo registro
         redirect('welcome/exito');
    }
```

Comment: Yo te recomendaria que no pusieras "pantallazos" de tu pantalla, ve y copia tu codigo, asi es mas facil para nosotro ayudarte.

Comment: Por lo que veo es que estas tratando de actualizar unos datos donde exista el nombre "Maria De Los Angeles", debes de tener en cuenta que esta no seria la forma correcta ya que si tu tienes miles de nombres es imposible que no exista uno con el mismo nombre por tal razon siempre es importante manejar un ID auto_increment y que sea un llave primaria....de tal manera podras hacer y deshacer todo lo que quieras con ese solo id....espero haberme hecho entender...y tu pregunta va un poco mas enfocada al SQL.